# tinyxml removes spaces before slash in self closing tags?

Tags: tinyxml2

Tinyxml is changing my XML file by removing spaces before the end of self-closing tags, which causes an error in my program.

Here is an example of the tag before it gets processed by tinyxml

```
<Name Value="" />
```

And here is it afterwards:

```
<Name Value=""/>
```

I'm wondering why tinyxml does this and whether there is a way of stopping it?

I've tried using `"compact=true"` and also set to false, there is no change.

Also using `PRESERVE_WHITESPACE` doesnt work because this only handles whitespace inside the tag?

It's really strange because I've been using this same script on a mac and it works fine. Now I move to windows and it is causing this problem and no way it seems to solve it.

Cheers

Comment: Maybe better to ask this on the TinyXml2 GitHub issues area?

Comment: Ask here: https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2/issues